# How to disable built-in JIT in Tailwindcss-v3

Tags: css, tailwind-css, jit

As some of my html comes from database, some of used CSS classes are not presented in HTML file in time of build `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css`.

So how can I disable JIT to have all possible CSS in `./dist/tailwind.css`?

Answer (score 2):

just-in-time engine or JIT is enabled by default on V3 and we don't have a key value to put on our tailwind.config file to disable it (at least for now).
The way they propose is use safelisting classes
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes
If you know which classes are, or at least the pattern you can declare those on the safelist.

```
safelist: [
    'bg-red-500',
    'text-3xl',
    'lg:text-4xl',
]
```

If you want to have all possible CSS you can try this but it will generate a huge css file (20M aprox) but maybe you can adapt it to what you need .

```
safelist: [
    {
        pattern: /.*/,
        variants: [
            "first",
            "last",
            "odd",
            "even",
            "visited",
            "checked",
            "empty",
            "read-only",
            "group-hover",
            "group-focus",
            "focus-within",
            "hover",
            "focus",
            "focus-visible",
            "active",
            "disabled",
        ],
    },
],
```

Comment: please apply formatting to your code